# Add new field to Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have this viewmodel

```
public class TipoProyectoViewModel
{      
    public string Category{ get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProjectType> Type{ get; set; }
}
```

and I was getting all my projects ordered by type

```
var category = _dbContext.Categoria 
    .Include( c => c.TipoProyecto )
    .Where( c => c.CategoryId == CategoryId )
    .GroupBy( e => e.CategoryName )
    .Select( e => new TipoProyectoViewModel() {
        Category = e.Key,
        Tipo = e.SelectMany( p => p.ProjectType )
    } )
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

This code returns something like this

```
Home //project category as string in my viewmodel
{
    Ienmuerable1
    Ienumerable2 //a list of ProjectType
    .....
}

Home //project category as string
{
    Ienmuerable1
    Ienumerable2 //a list of ProjectType
    .....
}
```

Now I want to add a new property to my viewmodel and get it from database

```
public class TipoProyectoViewModel
{   
    public string Glyphicons { get; set; }   
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProjectType> Type { get; set; }
}
```

The Glyphicons comes from my category table

```
public class Categoria
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProjectType> ProjectType { get; set; }
    public string Glyphicons { get; set; }  <<<<<glyphicons
}
```

How should I modify the Entity Framework query?

```
var category = _dbContext.Categoria
    .Include( c => c.TipoProyecto )
    .Where( c => c.CategoryId == CategoryId )
    .GroupBy( e => e.CategoryName )
    .Select( e => new TipoProyectoViewModel() {
        Category = e.Key,
        glyp=...,
        Tipo = e.SelectMany( p => p.ProjectType )
    } )
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Why do you need to treat `Glyphicons` any different to `Category`? Both are `string` properties with a 1:1 mapping.

Comment: what I want is to save in my database the glyphicon class from bootstrap, so when I render the categoryname , I also add the icon

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with what you actually said in your question. You asked how to change your query to get a `string` property in your model into a like-named `string` property in your view model. The answer is to assign directly from one to the other, just as you're already doing for `Category`.

Comment: I did not mention what I want to do with my front end to avoid adding complexity. Can you please write some code as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewModels are orthogonal to your Database Entity types.

You should create your ViewModel object directly and populate it outside of a query, like this:

```
public IActionResult Get()
{
    TipoProyectoViewModel viewModel = new TipoProyectoViewModel();

    using( var dbContext = ... )
    {
        var catgoryGroup = dbContext.Categoria
            .Include( c => c.TipoProyecto )
            .Where( c => c.CategoryId == CategoryId )
            .GroupBy( e => e.CategoryName )
            .FirstOrDefault();

        viewModel.Category = catgoryGroup.Key;
        viewModel.Tipo = categoryGroup
            .SelectMany( p => p.ProjectType )
            .ToList(); // Always call ToList() because you should never pass an IQueryable to your View!

        viewModel.Glyphicons = dbContext
            .Select( /* your query to get data for this property */ );
    }

    return this.View( viewModel );
}
```